# pyqt: how to set pointing hand cursor on element Qlabel?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I've created an element Qlabel: `self.labelOnlineHelp = QLabel('<a href="http://example.com">Online Help</a>')` and connected it:

```
def click():
    subprocess.check_call(['/usr/bin/firefox', "http://example.com"])
self.labelOnlineHelp.linkActivated.connect(click)
```

Now I am trying to add a pointing hand cursor when mouse hovers this qlabel. I tried to use this code:

```
def hovered(): 
    self.labelOnlineHelp.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
self.labelOnlineHelp.linkHovered.connect(hovered)
```

but I get an error: NameError: global name 'QtGui' is not defined

Comment: Did you remember to `import QtGui.QCursor`?

Comment: @JonHarper I have import of: `from PyQt4.QtGui import *
  from PyQt4.QtCore import *`. Maybe I use old version of pyqt.

Comment: It should be `QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor)`, then.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov That's actually going to be the answer if you want to write it up.